# Ajax Sending Null Parameters to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send 3 parameters using ajax to a Controller function. My ajax looks like

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../saveFields',
    data: {
           fields : fieldIDs,
           values : vals,
           ID : <%= this.Model.DatabaseID %>,
    },
    success: function (data) {
           alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
           alert("Failed");
    }
});
```

where fieldIDs and vals are arrays populated with integers. And the Controller call is

```
public ActionResult saveFields(int ID, int[] fields, int[] values)
```

I have a breakpoint set up right before the ajax call and the first line in the Controller function. Right before the ajax call, fieldIDs and vals are correctly populated, but then the first line of the Controller function the fields and values parameters are null. ID works fine. Any assistance as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you doing form post or json? what flavor of asp.net mvc are you using?

Comment: For sending arrays you might try setting `traditional: true` for the AJAX.

Comment: @NazaRN that did the trick, thank you so much! If you add that as an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Jquery has different types of param serialization. [Jquery Params](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

It turns out to fix that and pass an array correctly, you need to set the following property for the AJAX:

```
traditional: true
```